How to delete an island whose min x less than -1
I have several mesh islands inside -1 to 1 on both X and Y axis. I want Geometry Nodes to detect any island that has at least one of its points falling out of this -1 to 1 on both axis, and if so delete that island. How can I go about accomplishing this?

First I plug a Position node into a Vector Math node set to Absolute, this way all position values will be positive, i.e. if you want to check if values are below -1 or above +1, you can use a Compare node set to Greater Than 1.
So after getting the absolute values I take a Separate XYZ node and compare the X and Y values if they are greater than 1, the result I combine with a Boolean Math node set to Or, so that the result is always true if any X or Y value is outside the -1 to 1 range.
This value I plug into an Accumulate Field node, plug Island Index from a Mesh Island node into the Group Index, and the Total output I use as Selection for a Delete Geometry node (which I have set to Face domain here, but it works with Point and Edge as well).
As Geometry I have an external object referenced by an Object Info node consisting of some meshes, where some are outside the -1 to 1 range.

On the left is the original object, four mesh islands have corners outside the -1 to 1 range on X or Y which are marked in red. On the right is the result of the Geometry Nodes modifier. Of course this also works if the meshes are more complex or exceed the range on both axes.



Oh right, accumulate field... I think this is more performant than mine!

@MarkusvonBroady But just a little bit...

According to your test almost 10 times faster but according to Crantisz' test over 20 times faster

You can avoid a repeat zone which will be a life-saver if you have thousands or more of mesh islands, if you use the below trick: move each point satisfying a criterion for deletion to the coordinate equal to mesh island index, then for each vertex check by proximity if some vertex (at least one) of the same mesh island was moved:



Oh, although I made basically the same of course it is much simpler to check if something is outside the range with the Not Equal node and then set the according Epsilon value... how stupid of me :D

I personally like accumulate filed approach. Using island index as position looks a bit hacky for me. Plus proximity and set position look expensive from a computational point of view

...although the question asked explicitly for X and Y, which I assume means those are flat meshes where it would not matter if you check the Z value as well - but if there were meshes outside -1 and 1 on Z but those should not be deletedand only X and Y mattered, then you would have compare them separately and combine the results anyway, which would then not make much of a difference compared to my result. But still I annoyed that I did not think of "equal" and "epsilon" :D

@Crantisz Actually the timings don't say that Markus' setup is computational very expensive, in fact a lot less than yours... especially since yours does not even do what is asked for in the question...? It only checks for Z values lower than 0, while the question is about X and Y outside of -1 to 1.

I think conditions are a smaller part in the computational cost. There is only one way to check - testing

@Crantisz I tested with an object that contains several cubes (but not simple ones with only 8 vertices, a few more subdivisions) so that it has a total of 15,440 vertices. Your setup takes 41 ms, Markus' 5.9 ms and mine 1.2 ms (even though I expanded it to take all three axes into account).

conditions aren't a problem, repeat zones are (unfortunately). I could bet performance-wise it's Gordon > me > Crantisz here. As for Crantisz not answering the question exactly - I think it's fine, he shows the general technique, that can be easily adjusted, I often do that too.

@GordonBrinkmann I was 2 seconds late with my bet :D

@MarkusvonBroady You are right, the Repeat Zone becomes a real problem when you have a whole lot of vertices. For not answering: sure, the general technique can be adjusted, but especially when doubting the costs of other methods you should at least have something comparable... although in his case checking the X and Y as well and combining the results with the Z actually made his setup quicker than just checking a single axis, because the more axes you check for "outsiders", the less geometry is created in the repeat zone.

I have tested, so the results are: Gordon - 2.3ms, Markus - 50ms, mine - 230ms. And the reason is not because repeat zones are bad, but Separate Geometry calculated 100 times is bad. And I found a bug. Repeat zones don't calculate properly in frames.

It is not a bug, it was fixed in 4.2

@Crantisz repeat zones are slow. This is because they aren't tight loops in C, they are "wide loops" in the sense that they contain a stack machine evaluating the nodes. On top of that, usually when you iterate over stuff one-by-one inside a repeat zone, you are using a node like "delete geometry" or "set position" or "store named attribute"... All those nodes are actual loops, and just because you select only one element in the loop doesn't mean the entire geometry isn't iterated over. Had geonodes provided special single-element nodes, repeat zones would get much faster.

Here is the example how to remove all islands that Z is less then 0:

Basically, it loops through all islands and collect it if minimum of Z positions is grater than 0.

